# Getting 403 while trying to upload to GCP signed URL that was generated with multiple metadata

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I generated a GCP signed url with two metadata values in the header.

Example,
‘x-goog-meta-reviewer’:’jane’,
‘x-goog-meta-author’:’jack’

When I try to upload the file to the generated signed URL with the metadata set in the header .. I get 403 forbidden request.

But the interesting part is that the same code works fine if i just set one metadata 
    ‘x-goog-meta-reviewer’:’jane‘
    in both the headers.

Can we not send two metadata values while trying to upload a file to Google cloud?

Comment: 403 happens for unauthorized access, check the roles ,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you construct the [Canonical requests](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication/canonical-requests) you should keep in mind
the following for the Canonical Headers:

> 1.Make all header names lowercase.
>
> 2.Sort all headers by header name using a lexicographical sort by code
>   point value.
>
> 3.Separate each header with a newline (/n).
>
> 4.Eliminate duplicate header names by creating one header name with a
>   comma-separated list of values. Be sure there is no whitespace between
>   the values, and be sure that the order of the comma-separated list
>   matches the order that the headers appear in your request. For more
>   information, see RFC 7230 section 3.2.
>
> 5.Replace any folding whitespace or newlines (CRLF or LF) with a single
>   space. For more information about folding whitespace, see RFC 7230,
>   section 3.2.4..
>
> 6.Remove any whitespace around the colon that appears after the header
>   name.
>
> 7.For example, using the custom header x-goog-acl: private without
>   removing the space after the colon returns a 403 Forbidden error,
>   because the request signature you calculate does not match the
>   signature Google calculates.

Therefore you can get a 403 Forbidden error when the request signature you calculate does not match the signature Google calculates.

Comment: It worked like a charm!!!!. The Option 2 (Sort all headers by header name using a lexicographical sort by code point value.) helped me solve the issue. Kudos.

Answer (score 0):

For me I generated code from Postman and switching the order of the headers made it work.

```
  var config = {
method: 'put',
url: response.uploadUrl,
headers: {
  'content-type': 'application/zip',
  'x-goog-content-length-range': '0,104857600',
  ...data.getHeaders(),
},
data: data
};
```

vs.

```
  var config = {
method: 'put',
url: response.uploadUrl,
headers: {
  ...data.getHeaders(),
  'content-type': 'application/zip',
  'x-goog-content-length-range': '0,104857600',
},
data: data
```

};